# embedding youtube channels on a website and extracting channel data

Tags: mysql, youtube

hey everyone i have two questions pertaining to youtube:

1) how do you go about embedding youtube channels on your website? so far i've been using this method:

```
<script src="http://www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://www.google.com/ig/modules/youtube.xml&amp;up_channel=illbehonest&amp;synd=open&amp;w=320&amp;h=390&amp;title=&amp;border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&amp;output=js"></script>
```

and http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ChannelPlaylist

but none have proven to be really feasible!

2) how do you go about extracting youtube channel data for entry into a mysql database? (for example video title, time/date uploaded, url) is there any jquery plugin that does this?

many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same problem (point 1), and ended up rolling out my jquery based channel player. It's very simple and easy to extend and customize using css. It works also on iPad/iPhone, which was the weak point of the gmodules solution and other custom players.

It's here : http://code.google.com/p/jq-youtube-player/

Feel free to use it, customize it, improve it etc..

Regarding point 2 : you should ask a specific question, giving details about what programming language you are using and what/when you need to save on db.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to use YouTube's native API, probably, and make a call separate from the channel `script` tag. They have options in a number of different languages and tutorials/examples to go along with. Check it out [here](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/overview.html).

Hope that helps.